# Is there a *real* zerofree equivalent for btrfs?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, data

I have a 200G hdd in my virtual machine, and I don't want to fill the entire virtual hdd with zeroes, only inodes that need it.

Don't give me `sfill` or `cat /dev/zero >/tmp/file`. Those are not the same thing at all, because `zerofree` finds the **unallocated, non-zeroed blocks**. In other words it will only fill inodes that contain data no longer accessible because it was deleted but not wiped.

`sfill` or `cat` solution will fill **entire** filesystem free space with zeros, and not only inodes that need it.

Is there any `zerofree` equivalent for btrfs?

Comment: You might have a look at `fstrim`, which seems to be supported by [btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Does_Btrfs_support_TRIM.2Fdiscard.3F).